# How to set limits and margins in scatterplot matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I have this code for a scatterplot

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline
from matplotlib import style
style.use('ggplot')
plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))

x = merged_rizvan['rating.mean']
y = merged_rizvan['female_prob']
colors = ['blue', 'green']


fig, ax = plt.subplots()


ax.scatter(x, y)

ax.set_xlim(-50, 50)
ax.set_ylim(0,1)
ax.set_xlabel("Rating Mean \n (people's intuitions)")
ax.set_ylabel("Female Probability \n (classifier predictions)")
ax.legend()

#fig.text(0.05, 0.95, "Female", ha='left', va='top', fontsize=10)
fig.text(0.07, 0.05, "Male", ha='left', va='bottom', fontsize=10)
fig.text(0.90, 0.05, 'Female', ha='left', va='bottom', fontsize=10)

plt.xticks([-50, 0, 50])
plt.show()
```

but the result is not exactly what I'm looking for. There are some datapoints that are really close to 50 and -50 so they are basically going outside the plot.

[scatterplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsFss.png)

I need some margins, while keeping the xlim and ylim (so basically I want to still visualize -50 and 50) but when I try to add margin it doesn't properly change. Other than that I'd like to add 'female' and 'male' instead of -50 and 50. Do you have any suggestions?

**EDIT

I added this code and eventually solved the problem

```
z = 'Male'
w = 'Female'
ax.margins(0.15)
ax.set_yticklabels([z, w])
ax.set_xticklabels([z, w])
plt.xticks([-50, 50])
plt.yticks([0,1])
```

Comment: Maybe `ax.scatter(x, y, clip_on=False)` works for you?  And `ax.set_xticks([-50, 0, 50], ['Male', '', 'Female'])`?

Comment: thank you for the answer! I actually added some code eventually and I solve the problem, let me update the question